# Costa Rica connecting flight

Tags: transit, transit-visas

I am Haitian, I have a flight from Egypt to Guatemala. But I have a 1 hour 35 minutes layover at Costa Rica Airport. Will I need a transit visa?

Comment: Apparently you need a visa to transit or enter Costa Rica, unless you have US or Schengen visa. But are your two flights on the same ticket? If they’re not you are quite unlikely to be able to make the connection. What’s your full itinerary?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My flight is from Egypt, I will make a first stop in Switzerland and the second stop in Costa Rica for only 1 hour 35 minutes and fly to Guatemala. Same ticket